# Points freezed in OpenLayers when adding data to different layer

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a map using OpenLayers with 2 points vector layers ( layer A  & Layer B ) , layer A already contains hundreds of points and navigating well and layer B without features, whenever I add new features to layer B, features will be added without any problem but when I try to zoom in & zoom out the map, I have found that points in layer A freezed and not in correct places and I got the below script errors in OpenLayers.js file.

*Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node*

OpenLayers version 2.12

Comment: No one get this before ??